# selenium xpath locator is not working: timeOutException

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a page where after inspecting I found that it gives,

```
<a class="SomeClass" href="#/sObject/701R00000004qi1IAA/view" title="Test;a">Test<a--></a>"
```

and I want to verify if page has the `701R00000004qi1IAA` ID there. I am using following code:

```
locator = "/a[contains(@href,'" +ID+"')]"
```

and then

```
getWebDriverUtil.waitForElementPresent(By.xpath(locator), 10000 ).isDisplayed();
```

but I am getting `timeOutException`. But manually I can confirm the field with id is there on that target page.
What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Have a look at [implicit wait time](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits)

Comment: findElements can loop through all //a[@class ='someclass'] and if you get the outerHtml for each then you can see if your id is wrong. Are there iframes on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Your locator: /a[contains(@href,'" +ID+"')]

/a - try searching in the whole document with "//a", not on the first level only

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you Boris but unfortunately this change dint work. Its still failing with same exception.

Comment: 'some exception' kinda leaves me in a dead end.

Comment: I meant same exception: TimeoutException.

Comment: ok this means 2 things. 1. element is not there. 2. locator is wrong. try this: "//a[contains(@href,'701R00000004qi1IAA')]" That should work

Answer (score 0):

I would also try using a *double slash* to search for the link anywhere inside the DOM:

```
//a[contains(@href, '" + ID + "')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath locator is correct. Check with explicit waits instead of elementpresent method.

```
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(locator)));
```

This waits up to 10 seconds before throwing a `TimeoutException` or if it finds the element will return it in 0 - 10 seconds. `WebDriverWait` by default calls the `ExpectedCondition` every 500 milliseconds until it returns successfully.

Here you can able to increase Webdriver wait time. Hope you get the result successful.